# Resources injection doesn't work when running jms examples in eclipse.

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jms, code-injection

I want to run the jms tutorial files in eclipse. I have configured glassfish properly and added the jms resources. It works ok if I run it in netbeans.

I created an "application client project" in eclipse.

Here is where the resources get injected:

```
 @Resource(mappedName = "jms/ConnectionFactory")
 private static ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
 @Resource(mappedName = "jms/Queue")
 private static Queue queue;
 @Resource(mappedName = "jms/Topic")
 private static Topic topic;
```

Then, when it gets here:

```
connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
```

I get a NullPointerException. For some reason it doesn't get the resources from the server so they are null.

It works if I build the project in eclipse and then run it from a command line using appclient:

```
 appclient Producer topic 4
```

It says here http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.j2ee.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Fcjappcliproj.html that:

> An application client module is used to contain a full-function client
>   Java™ application (non Web-based) that connects to and uses the Java
>   EE resources defined in your server. When you place the client code in
>   an application client module instead of a simple JAR file, the
>   application client benefits from the server's resources (it does not
>   need to re-specify the class path to Java EE and server JAR files) as
>   well as from easier JNDI lookup (the client container fills in the
>   initial context and other parameters).

So it seems that I am on the right track, but maybe I am missing some eclipse configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've already noticed, if you run your Application in standalone mode you will not be able to access servers resources, this is by design. You need to use Glassfish `appclient` (or similar tools for other application servers) in order to run a Java EE Client App.
Heres another thread that may help you configure your project to run correctly: [eclipse howto start a application client on java ee glassfish appl srv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044682/eclipse-howto-start-a-application-client-on-java-ee-glassfish-appl-srv).