# Trouble injecting JMS resources with Java EE 7 and Glassfish 4.0

Tags: jms, jndi, netbeans-7, glassfish-4, java-ee-7

I tried to use

```
 @Resource(mappedName = "jms/ConnectionFactory")
 private static ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
 @Resource(mappedName = "jms/Queue")
 private static Queue queue;
```

to instantiate JMS stuff inside my application running in Glassfish (4.0).

I created these resources via the NetBeans (7.4rc1) Wizards and saw that they created a glassfish-resources.xml in /setup/ with this connector-resource.
I verified per Glassfish's *asadmin list-jms-resources* command (and in the web-based admin page) that the resources are available.

But whenever I try to access these fields inside my application they are **null**.

I saw that this problem can happen when running the application in eclipse ([Resources injection doesn't work when running jms examples in eclipse.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195125/resources-injection-doesnt-work-when-running-jms-examples-in-eclipse))
but I start my application from NetBeans (which automatically starts integrated Glassfish and brings - I thought - everything out-of-the-box).

I also saw [Trouble injecting resources with Java EE 6 and Glassfish 3.1 using @Resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422577/trouble-injecting-resources-with-java-ee-6-and-glassfish-3-1-using-resource) but cross-checked that the lookup name is already correct.

Other hints what I have to care of to get the JNDI lookup work?